# Design Ring Oscillator using Quartus 2

Tags: verilog, fpga, quartus

I have designed a Ring Oscillator to implement on FPGA using Alter's Quartus 2. I want to tell the tool not to optimise ring oscillator away. For that, I need a Synthesis tool for my FPGA (Altera DE2-07). Can you tell me how can I do this to prevent logic optimization?

Thank You.

```
module ringOscitry (
   en,
   w1,
   w2,
   w3,
   w4
);

input en;
output w1,w2,w3,w4;  //RTL

assign w4 = en & w3;
assign w1 = ~ w4;
assign w2 = ~ w1;
assign w3 = ~ w2;

endmodule



module ringosi(enable, w1, w2, w3, w4);
    input enable;
    output w1, w2, w3, w4;

    and u1(w4, enable, w3);
    not #5 u2(w1, w4); //Gate_level
    not #5 u3(w2, w1);
    not #5 u4(w3, w2);
endmodule



module top(en,w1,w2,w3,w4);
input en;
output w1,w2,w3,w4;
ringOscitry  c1 (en, w1, w2, w3, w4);
ringosi  c2 (enable, w1,w2, w3,w4);

endmodule
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gncMA.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a reset signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712976/generating-a-reset-signal)

Comment: Maybe you can post your code so we can look at it and understand why the optimization is occurring in the first place.

Comment: @RichMaes I have posted circuit diagram and verilog code for your details, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

So design of the ring oscillator not withstanding, I would suggest the following relative to preventing optimization.

inside of your RTL,

```
(* altera_attribute = {"-name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION FORCED_IF_ASYNCHRONOUS; -name DONT_MERGE_REGISTER ON; -name PRESERVE_REGISTER ON;}  *)
output reg w1;
(* altera_attribute = {"-name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION FORCED_IF_ASYNCHRONOUS; -name DONT_MERGE_REGISTER ON; -name PRESERVE_REGISTER ON;}  *)
output reg w2;
(* altera_attribute = {"-name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION FORCED_IF_ASYNCHRONOUS; -name DONT_MERGE_REGISTER ON; -name PRESERVE_REGISTER ON;}  *)
output reg w3;
(* altera_attribute = {"-name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION FORCED_IF_ASYNCHRONOUS; -name DONT_MERGE_REGISTER ON; -name PRESERVE_REGISTER ON;}  *)
output reg w4;
```

And then re-write your combinatorial logic to be like this.  This code makes me cringe... but I guess you know what you are doing relative to this oscillator.  I believe the directives above will prevent optimization of w1-w4.  Good luck.

```
always @ (*)
begin
    w4 <= en & w3;
    w3 <= ~w4;
    w2 <= ~w1;
    w1 <= ~w1;
end
```